# Best way to evaluate a series of products in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Say I have a 1D array of [a1, a2, a3, ..., an], and I want the array [a1, a1a2, a1a2a3, ..., a1a2...an]. Is this possible to compute using numpy's routines? At the moment, I am using a loop whereby each element is the previous element multiplied by the new `a'. However, this is understanably quite slow.

EDIT:

For clarification. I have a 1D array containing n elements. I would like to produce a new 1D array of n elements. The first element in the new array is the first element in the old array. The second element in the new array is the product of the first two elements in the old array.

In general, the m-th element of the new array is the product of the first m elements of the old array.

Hopefully this clears things up a bit.

Comment: It's not clear how exactly you want your output list to look.

Comment: Sorry, I'll try to clarify my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `np.cumprod`

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.rand(10)
p = np.cumprod(a)

print(p)
```